# How to transfer money from a connected managed account to the platform account using stripe.net

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

Title says it all.

I have several managed account on my platform.  I would like to know how I can transfer money out of them and into my platform's account.  This is how I hope to collect my platforms fee as I want to take a lump sum monthly and not collect based on percentage of a charge/transfer.

Comment: Currently, Stripe does not support moving funds from a connected account to a platform account. Sorry!

Comment: Can't transfer from connect account to platform.  Can't add lum sum fee to connect account transfers.  Can't have a lum sum fee on subscriptions.  Stripe is really testing my patience now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do this is to create a customer along with the managed account and use that to make ach transfers.  Guess I need to figure out how to do that now...